# need information on installation of hl7 - fhir server

Tags: installation, hl7-fhir

I am new to the FHIR framework. We are planning to install FHIR latest version on our college server and try to work on implementing APIs on the FHIR. However, i couldn't find any useful link with instructions on how to install FHIR and it's resources. Can anyone do the needful please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't 'install FHIR' - that would be like 'installing HTML'. Perhaps you're looking for one of the test servers? - see http://wiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=Publicly_Available_FHIR_Servers_for_testing

Comment: Thanks Grahame for taking time to answer my question... However my requirement is that my professor wants me to host FHIR from our university server so that we can build things and carry on research. Please help me... Thanks in advance..

Comment: The look at the link above

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to create and host your own FHIR server, you could look at the [Furore Spark server](https://github.com/furore-fhir/spark) (based on .Net) or the skeleton server of [HAPI FHIR](https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir) (Java based). These are open source, so you can download and install them and change them to fit your needs.

When you only need to develop client side applications, like most people, you can test them with the test servers Grahame has pointed you to. Both for .Net and Java there are already very good APIs available through NuGet or Maven, making it easier to start with client side development.